# Typescript cast generic function arguments to object

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

How to create generic function type with casting it's arguments to as part of return type. Something like that:

```
interface Actions {
  [fn: string]: <T>(...args: T[]){
      type: string;
      payload: {...T}
  }
}
```

I mean that **payload** should be an object which contains properties related to function arguments and it's types.

It's an example how it should work:

```
const someActions: Actions {

  // valid type method (has the same payload structure as arguments)
  addItem: (item: SomeItemType){
    type: "ADD_NEW_ITEM",
    payload: { item }
  },

  // invalid type method (has different payload and arguments structure)
  removeItem: (itemId: number, mode: SomeModeType){
    type: "REMOVE_ITEM",
    payload: {id : 0}
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how such a signature will look ? for example if args are `{ a: 1 }, {b: 2}` the result should be `{a: number, b: number}` ?

Comment: Hi, I added an example

Comment: Your example is a bit confusing since it is not valid TypeScript.  Can you provide an example of your current working code (which requires the cast you mention)?